# como agregar opcion de jugador vs jugador a un juego de tic toe en python?

Tags: python

Buenas hace algunos dias, consegui un juego de tic tac toe escrito en codigo de python, pero solo tiene el modo de jugador vs cpu, me gustaria saber como puedo alterar este codigo para que tambien tenga modo jugador vs jugador. Soy nuevo programando con python.

ya he intentado agregar un codigo externo con funciones que habia realizado del jugador vs jugador, tambien escrito en python, pero no se como agregar las funciones que ya realize al codigo que tiene cpu. adjunto dejo el codigo que he realizado cpu vs jugador

```
    print(20*" ","   referencia:    ")
    print(20*" ","     |    |      ") 
    print(20*" ","  1  | 2  | 3    ")
    print(20*" ","-----+----+----- ")
    print(20*" ","     |    |      ")
    print(20*" ","  4  | 5  | 6    ")
    print(20*" ","-----+----+----- ")
    print(20*" ","     |    |      ")
    print(20*" ","  7  | 8  | 9    \n")
    
    
    def dibujar_pizarra():
        print()
        print("                               Referencia:")
        print("     |    |     ",10*" ","     |    |   ",)
        print("  "+pizarra[1]+"  | "+pizarra[2]+"  | "+pizarra[3]+"   ",10*" ","  1  | 2  | 3  ")
        print("-----+----+-----",10*" ","-----+----+-----")
        print("     |    |     ",10*" ","     |    |     ")
        print("  "+pizarra[4]+"  | "+pizarra[5]+"  | "+pizarra[6]+"   ",10*" ","  4  | 5  | 6   ")
        print("-----+----+-----",10*" ","-----+----+-----")
        print("     |    |     ",10*" ","     |    |      ")
        print("  "+pizarra[7]+"  | "+pizarra[8]+"  | "+pizarra[9]+"   ",10*" ","  7  | 8  | 9    \n\n")
    
    
    def entrada_jugador_persona(eleccion):
        eleccion = eleccion.upper()
        while True:
            inp_preg1 = input(f"Jugador {eleccion} Elige tu opcion, recuerda seguir  el\norden de referencia que se ha colocado a tu mano derecha: ")
            if inp_preg1.isdigit() and int(inp_preg1) <10 and int(inp_preg1) >0:
                inp_preg1 = int(inp_preg1)
                if pizarra[inp_preg1] == " ":
                    return inp_preg1
                else:
                    print(f"Jugador {eleccion} Esa opcion ya esta llena.")
            else:
                print(f"Jugador {eleccion} elige una opcion entre los numeros 1 al 9 ")
    
    
    def ganador(eleccion,pizarra):
        ganador_lugar = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9],[1,5,9],[3,5,7]]
        for casilla_jugador in ganador_lugar:
            if pizarra[casilla_jugador[0]] == pizarra[casilla_jugador[1]] == pizarra[casilla_jugador[2]] == eleccion:
                return True
    
    
    def movimiento_ganador(i,pizarra,eleccion):
        pizarra_temporal = list(pizarra)
        pizarra_temporal[i] = eleccion
        if ganador(eleccion,pizarra_temporal):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
    
    def opcion_cpu(cpu , Jugador , pizarra):
        for i in range(1,10):
            if pizarra[i] == " " and movimiento_ganador(i,pizarra,cpu):
                return i
        for i in range(1,10):
            if pizarra[i] == " " and movimiento_ganador(i,pizarra,Jugador):
                return i
        for i in [5,1,7,3,2,9,8,6,4]:
            if pizarra[i] == " ":
                return i
    
    def jugar_de_nuevo():
        while True:
            ciclo = input("Jugador, quieres jugar nuevamente, digita Si, para continuar o No para salir ")
            if ciclo in["y","Y", "si", "Si", "SI", "sI", "s", "S"]:
                validar_nuevo_juego = True
                break
            elif ciclo in ["n","N", "No", "no", "nO"]:
                print("Gracias por jugar conmigo! ")
                validar_nuevo_juego = False
                break
            else:
                print("Intentalo nuevamente, indica el valor de tu ficha, X o O ")
        if validar_nuevo_juego:
            print("__________NEW GAME__________")
            juego_fuente()
        else:
            return False
    
     
    def chequear_ganador(Jugador , cpu):
        ganador_lugar = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9],[1,5,9],[3,5,7]]
        for casilla_ganadora in ganador_lugar:
            if pizarra[casilla_ganadora[0]] == pizarra[casilla_ganadora[1]] == pizarra[casilla_ganadora[2]] == Jugador:
                print("Jugador GANASTES!")
                if not jugar_de_nuevo():
                    return False
            elif pizarra[casilla_ganadora[0]] == pizarra[casilla_ganadora[1]] == pizarra[casilla_ganadora[2]] == cpu:
                    print("CPU GANO!")
                    if not jugar_de_nuevo():
                        return False
        if " " not in pizarra:
            print("EMPATE")
            if not jugar_de_nuevo():
                return False
        return True
    
    
    def ficha_jugador():
        while True:
            jugador_1 = input("jugador, indicame tu nombre ... ")
            jugador_1 = jugador_1.upper()
            inp_preg2 = input(f"{jugador_1} Indica, cual sera tu ficha, X o O ")
            if inp_preg2 in ["x" , "X"]:
                print(f"{jugador_1} tu opcion fue la X.\ntu juegas primero")
                return "x","o"
            elif inp_preg2 in ["O","o"]:
                print(f"{jugador_1} tu opcion fue la O.\nCpu juega primero")
                return "o","x"
            else:
                print(f"{jugador_1} indica una de las fichas X o O!")
    
    
    def juego_fuente():
        # Variable global
        global pizarra
        jugar = True
        pizarra =[""," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "]
        Jugador , cpu = ficha_jugador()
        dibujar_pizarra()
        while jugar:
            if Jugador == "x":
                x = entrada_jugador_persona(Jugador)
                pizarra[x] = Jugador
                dibujar_pizarra()
                jugar = chequear_ganador(Jugador , cpu)
                if jugar:
                    o = opcion_cpu(cpu , Jugador , pizarra)
                    print(f"Cpu Eligio:{o}")
                    pizarra[o] = cpu
                    dibujar_pizarra()
                    play = chequear_ganador(Jugador , cpu)
            else:
                x = opcion_cpu(cpu , Jugador , pizarra)
                print(f"Cpu Eligio:{x}")
                pizarra[x] = cpu
                dibujar_pizarra()
                play = chequear_ganador(Jugador , cpu)
                if play:
                    o = entrada_jugador_persona(Jugador)
                    pizarra[o] = Jugador
                    dibujar_pizarra()
                    play = chequear_ganador(Jugador , cpu)
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        juego_fuente()
```

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente un juego de tic-tac-toe cuenta con:

- Una función que imprima el tablero con las posiciones ocupadas actualizadas.
- Una función que revise luego de cada ronda si hay un ganador.
- Una interfaz que informe de quien es el turno y permita ingresar la celda que quiera ocupar.

Todo esto ya lo tenemos :)

Con esto sabido, el código, **creado en base al que tenías**, quedaría de la siguiente manera (aviso esto porque se que no estoy contemplando buenas practicas,
tambien se que hay código de más y que el juego puede elaborarse sin tantas lineas de codigo, de manera más eficiente, y con una
mejor interfaz -> esto para las personas que vienen a criticar código de gente que recién comienza, entiendan que si prefiero contestar asi es porque ayuda al que el colega comprenda mejor como se incorporó la funcionalidad a **su código**):

```py
print(20*" ","   Referencia:    ")
print(20*" ","     |    |      ") 
print(20*" ","  1  | 2  | 3    ")
print(20*" ","-----+----+----- ")
print(20*" ","     |    |      ")
print(20*" ","  4  | 5  | 6    ")
print(20*" ","-----+----+----- ")
print(20*" ","     |    |      ")
print(20*" ","  7  | 8  | 9    \n")


def dibujar_pizarra():
    print()
    print("                               Referencia:")
    print("     |    |     ",10*" ","     |    |   ",)
    print("  "+pizarra[1]+"  | "+pizarra[2]+"  | "+pizarra[3]+"   ",10*" ","  1  | 2  | 3  ")
    print("-----+----+-----",10*" ","-----+----+-----")
    print("     |    |     ",10*" ","     |    |     ")
    print("  "+pizarra[4]+"  | "+pizarra[5]+"  | "+pizarra[6]+"   ",10*" ","  4  | 5  | 6   ")
    print("-----+----+-----",10*" ","-----+----+-----")
    print("     |    |     ",10*" ","     |    |      ")
    print("  "+pizarra[7]+"  | "+pizarra[8]+"  | "+pizarra[9]+"   ",10*" ","  7  | 8  | 9    \n\n")


# Cambiamos el nombre de esta funcion ya que ahora solo son personas XD
def entrada_jugador(eleccion):
    eleccion = eleccion.upper()
    while True:
        inp_preg1 = input(f"{eleccion} Es tu turno: Elige tu opcion, recuerda seguir  el\norden de referencia que se ha colocado a tu mano derecha: ")
        if inp_preg1.isdigit() and int(inp_preg1) <10 and int(inp_preg1) >0:
            inp_preg1 = int(inp_preg1)
            if pizarra[inp_preg1] == " ":
                return inp_preg1
            else:
                print(f"{eleccion} Esta opcion ya esta ocupada.")
        else:
            print(f"{eleccion} porfavor elige una opcion entre los numeros 1 al 9 ")


def ganador(eleccion,pizarra):
    ganador_lugar = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9],[1,5,9],[3,5,7]]
    for casilla_jugador in ganador_lugar:
        if pizarra[casilla_jugador[0]] == pizarra[casilla_jugador[1]] == pizarra[casilla_jugador[2]] == eleccion:
            return True


# Ya no necesitamos de movimiento_ganador ni de opcion_cpu


def jugar_de_nuevo():
    while True:
        ciclo = input("Quieren jugar nuevamente, digita Si, para continuar o No para salir ")
        if ciclo in["y","Y", "si", "Si", "SI", "sI", "s", "S"]:
            validar_nuevo_juego = True
            break
        elif ciclo in ["n","N", "No", "no", "nO"]:
            print("Gracias por jugar conmigo! ")
            validar_nuevo_juego = False
            break
        else:
            print("Intentalo nuevamente, indica el valor de tu ficha, X o O ")
    if validar_nuevo_juego:
        print("__________NEW GAME__________")
        juego_fuente()
    else:
        return False

 
# Estaria bueno que imprima los nombres ;)
def chequear_ganador(jugador_1 , jugador_2):
    ganador_lugar = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9],[1,5,9],[3,5,7]]
    for casilla_ganadora in ganador_lugar:
        if pizarra[casilla_ganadora[0]] == pizarra[casilla_ganadora[1]] == pizarra[casilla_ganadora[2]] == jugador_1:
            print("jugador_1 GANASTE!")
            if not jugar_de_nuevo():
                return False
        elif pizarra[casilla_ganadora[0]] == pizarra[casilla_ganadora[1]] == pizarra[casilla_ganadora[2]] == jugador_2:
                print("jugador_2 GANASTE")
                if not jugar_de_nuevo():
                    return False
    if " " not in pizarra:
        print("EMPATE")
        if not jugar_de_nuevo():
            return False
    return True


def ficha_jugador():
    jugador_1 = input("jugador 1, indicame tu nombre ... ")
    jugador_1 = jugador_1.upper()
    # Vamos a pedir lo mismo para un nuevo jugador 2 -> este jugara con la ficha que sobre
    jugador_2 = input("jugador 2, indicame tu nombre ...")
    jugador_2 = jugador_2.upper()
    while True:
        ficha_elegida = input(f"{jugador_1} Indica, cual sera tu ficha, X o O ")
        if ficha_elegida in ["x" , "X"]:
            print(f"{jugador_1} tu opcion fue la X. (JUEGAS PRIMERO)")
            print(f"{jugador_2} tu juegas con la O.\n")
            return "x","o"
        elif ficha_elegida in ["O","o"]:
            print(f"{jugador_1} tu opcion fue la O.")
            print(f"{jugador_2} tu juegas con la X. (JUEGAS PRIMERO)\n")
            return "o","x"
        else:
            print(f"{jugador_1} indica una de las fichas X o O!")


def juego_fuente():
    # Variable global
    global pizarra
    jugar = True
    pizarra =[""," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "]
    # Basicamente ahora cpu pasa a ser jugador_2 y usamos la funcion entrada_jugador 
    # para que seleccione su celda
    jugador_1 , jugador_2 = ficha_jugador()
    dibujar_pizarra()
    while jugar:
        if jugador_1 == "x":
            x = entrada_jugador(jugador_1)
            pizarra[x] = jugador_1
            dibujar_pizarra()
            jugar = chequear_ganador(jugador_1 , jugador_2)
            if jugar:
                o = entrada_jugador(jugador_2)
                pizarra[o] = jugador_2
                dibujar_pizarra()
                play = chequear_ganador(jugador_1 , jugador_2)
        else:
            x = entrada_jugador(jugador_2)
            pizarra[x] = jugador_2
            dibujar_pizarra()
            play = chequear_ganador(jugador_1 , jugador_2)
            if play:
                o = entrada_jugador(jugador_1)
                pizarra[o] = jugador_1
                dibujar_pizarra()
                play = chequear_ganador(jugador_1 , jugador_2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    juego_fuente()
```

##### Edit: Agrego la elección de modo de juego

Este código si bien cumple lo que pedís, puede **mejorarse un monton**, te animo a que intentes lograrlo, a mejorar la interfaz con el usuario, los comentarios, etc etc etc, es un ejercicio que te va a ayudar a crecer muchisimo :)

```py
print(20*" ","   Referencia:    ")
print(20*" ","     |    |      ") 
print(20*" ","  1  | 2  | 3    ")
print(20*" ","-----+----+----- ")
print(20*" ","     |    |      ")
print(20*" ","  4  | 5  | 6    ")
print(20*" ","-----+----+----- ")
print(20*" ","     |    |      ")
print(20*" ","  7  | 8  | 9    \n")


def dibujar_pizarra():
    print()
    print("                               Referencia:")
    print("     |    |     ",10*" ","     |    |   ",)
    print("  "+pizarra[1]+"  | "+pizarra[2]+"  | "+pizarra[3]+"   ",10*" ","  1  | 2  | 3  ")
    print("-----+----+-----",10*" ","-----+----+-----")
    print("     |    |     ",10*" ","     |    |     ")
    print("  "+pizarra[4]+"  | "+pizarra[5]+"  | "+pizarra[6]+"   ",10*" ","  4  | 5  | 6   ")
    print("-----+----+-----",10*" ","-----+----+-----")
    print("     |    |     ",10*" ","     |    |      ")
    print("  "+pizarra[7]+"  | "+pizarra[8]+"  | "+pizarra[9]+"   ",10*" ","  7  | 8  | 9    \n\n")


# Cambiamos el nombre de esta funcion ya que ahora solo son personas XD
def entrada_jugador(eleccion):
    eleccion = eleccion.upper()
    while True:
        inp_preg1 = input(f"{eleccion} Es tu turno: Elige tu opcion, recuerda seguir  el\norden de referencia que se ha colocado a tu mano derecha: ")
        if inp_preg1.isdigit() and int(inp_preg1) <10 and int(inp_preg1) >0:
            inp_preg1 = int(inp_preg1)
            if pizarra[inp_preg1] == " ":
                return inp_preg1
            else:
                print(f"{eleccion} Esta opcion ya esta ocupada.")
        else:
            print(f"{eleccion} porfavor elige una opcion entre los numeros 1 al 9 ")


def ganador(eleccion,pizarra):
    ganador_lugar = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9],[1,5,9],[3,5,7]]
    for casilla_jugador in ganador_lugar:
        if pizarra[casilla_jugador[0]] == pizarra[casilla_jugador[1]] == pizarra[casilla_jugador[2]] == eleccion:
            return True


# Volvemos a usar las funciones para jugar contra la cpu
def movimiento_ganador(i,pizarra,eleccion):
        pizarra_temporal = list(pizarra)
        pizarra_temporal[i] = eleccion
        if ganador(eleccion,pizarra_temporal):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
    
def opcion_cpu(cpu , Jugador , pizarra):
    for i in range(1,10):
        if pizarra[i] == " " and movimiento_ganador(i,pizarra,cpu):
            return i
    for i in range(1,10):
        if pizarra[i] == " " and movimiento_ganador(i,pizarra,Jugador):
            return i
    for i in [5,1,7,3,2,9,8,6,4]:
        if pizarra[i] == " ":
            return i


def jugar_de_nuevo():
    while True:
        ciclo = input("Quieren jugar nuevamente, digita Si, para continuar o No para salir ")
        if ciclo in["y","Y", "si", "Si", "SI", "sI", "s", "S"]:
            validar_nuevo_juego = True
            break
        elif ciclo in ["n","N", "No", "no", "nO"]:
            print("Gracias por jugar conmigo! ")
            validar_nuevo_juego = False
            break
        else:
            print("Intentalo nuevamente, indica el valor de tu ficha, X o O ")
    if validar_nuevo_juego:
        print("__________NEW GAME__________")
        juego_fuente()
    else:
        return False

 
# Estaria bueno que imprima los nombres ;)
def chequear_ganador(jugador_1 , jugador_2):
    ganador_lugar = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9],[1,5,9],[3,5,7]]
    for casilla_ganadora in ganador_lugar:
        if pizarra[casilla_ganadora[0]] == pizarra[casilla_ganadora[1]] == pizarra[casilla_ganadora[2]] == jugador_1:
            print("jugador_1 GANASTE!")
            if not jugar_de_nuevo():
                return False
        elif pizarra[casilla_ganadora[0]] == pizarra[casilla_ganadora[1]] == pizarra[casilla_ganadora[2]] == jugador_2:
                print("jugador_2 GANASTE")
                if not jugar_de_nuevo():
                    return False
    if " " not in pizarra:
        print("EMPATE")
        if not jugar_de_nuevo():
            return False
    return True


def ficha_jugador(modo):
    jugador_1 = input("jugador 1, indicame tu nombre ... ")
    jugador_1 = jugador_1.upper()
    if (modo == '1'):
        # Vamos a pedir lo mismo para un nuevo jugador 2 -> este jugara con la ficha que sobre
        jugador_2 = input("jugador 2, indicame tu nombre ... ")
        jugador_2 = jugador_2.upper()
    else:
        jugador_2 = "CPU"
    while True:
        ficha_elegida = input(f"{jugador_1} Indica, cual sera tu ficha, X o O ")
        if ficha_elegida in ["x" , "X"]:
            print(f"{jugador_1} tu opcion fue la X. (JUEGAS PRIMERO)")
            print(f"{jugador_2} tu juegas con la O.\n")
            return "x","o"
        elif ficha_elegida in ["O","o"]:
            print(f"{jugador_1} tu opcion fue la O.")
            print(f"{jugador_2} tu juegas con la X. (JUEGAS PRIMERO)\n")
            return "o","x"
        else:
            print(f"{jugador_1} indica una de las fichas X o O!")


# NUEVA FUNCION
def modo_de_juego():
    """
    Interfaz con el usuario para la eleccion del modo de juego

    :return: 1 || 2 Dependiendo del modo de juego que haya elegido
    """
    print("Bienvenido a tictactoe\nElija el modo de juego:\n [1] Modo multijugador\n [2] Modo un solo jugador");
    modo = input ("Modo de juego: ")
    while modo not in ['1','2']:
        print("Modo de juego desconocido")
        print("Elija el modo de juego:\n [1] Modo un solo jugador\n [2] Modo multijugador")
        modo = input ("Modo de juego: ")
    return modo


def juego_fuente():
    # Variable global
    global pizarra
    jugar = True
    pizarra =[""," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "]
    # Basicamente ahora cpu pasa a ser jugador_2 y usamos la funcion entrada_jugador 
    # para que seleccione su celda
    modo = modo_de_juego()
    # Ahora pasamos el modo de juego para ver si es necesario pedir el nombre de jugador_2
    jugador_1 , jugador_2 = ficha_jugador(modo)
    dibujar_pizarra()
    while jugar:
        if jugador_1 == "x":
            x = entrada_jugador(jugador_1)
            pizarra[x] = jugador_1
            dibujar_pizarra()
            jugar = chequear_ganador(jugador_1 , jugador_2)
            if jugar and modo == '1':
                o = entrada_jugador(jugador_2)
                pizarra[o] = jugador_2
                dibujar_pizarra()
                jugar = chequear_ganador(jugador_1 , jugador_2)
            elif jugar and modo == '2':
                o = opcion_cpu(jugador_2 , jugador_1 , pizarra)
                print(f"CPU ELIGIO:{o}")
                pizarra[o] = jugador_2
                dibujar_pizarra()
                jugar = chequear_ganador(jugador_1 , jugador_2)
        else:
            x = entrada_jugador(jugador_2)
            pizarra[x] = jugador_2
            dibujar_pizarra()
            jugar = chequear_ganador(jugador_1 , jugador_2)
            if jugar and modo == '1':
                o = entrada_jugador(jugador_1)
                pizarra[o] = jugador_1
                dibujar_pizarra()
                jugar = chequear_ganador(jugador_1 , jugador_2)
            elif jugar and modo == '2':
                o = opcion_cpu(jugador_2 , jugador_1 , pizarra)
                pizarra[o] = jugador_1
                dibujar_pizarra()
                jugar = chequear_ganador(jugador_1 , jugador_2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    juego_fuente()
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos

Comment: Me ha servido de maravilla, ya estaba realizando otro código, pero este que has realizado es mucho mejor que lo que estaba haciendo, pero sigo con la duda de como puedo unir estos dos modos en un solo codigo? queria intentarlo por el metodo If pero me daria unas 500 lineas de codigo y supongo que hay opciones mas viables. La verdad he buscado mucho pero por mi experiencia no se implementarlo.

Comment: Ahi edité el código para poder jugar en los dos modos, espero que te sirva y mucha suerte :)

Comment: vale muchisimas gracias, voy a intentar mejorarlo y dejarlo en este canal, a pesar de ser nuevo en este lenguaje de programacion, estoy intentando realizar mis propias versiones para aprender mucho mas